# How to implement pyodbc with Django and how to store passwords for databases?

Tags: python, django, database, pyodbc

I developed a Django application, where a user can change the database dynamically through the UI.
I tried using Django's integrated database configurations in settings.py but I had to do some workarounds but still faced some weird errors.
Therefore I decided to use pyodbc with a connection string to connect to the database in my views.py.
The User inputs his database credentials (table, user, password, host, port), which then get saved on a database.
Every time a user needs some data following method gets invoked:

```
con = DatabaseConnection.objects.all().first()
conn_str = '{}/{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(con.user, con.password, con.host, con.port, con.name)
```

Everything works fine, but how exactly do I store the password(or the rest of the data) correctly?
I thought about encrypting and decrypting the password in my views.py but that wouldn't make sense, would it?

Comment: I wouldnt save the password in the Database , instead evert time the user want to  use the DB connection I would ask him to put his password again

Comment: @NirElbaz How would you save the password, when the user calls a different page?
Would you cache it?

Comment: I am not sure how you implement the connection with the DB, but if it is a class, create an instance with the user name and password ,and so long the session in on there is no issue

Comment: Ah, I see. Thx :D